# Google action simulator missing dialog box

Tags: simulator, voice-recognition, actions-on-google

I'm trying to get my first Google Action up and running, following the instructions [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-say-number-nodejs). But when I start the simulator, I do not see a dialog box where I can type! See simulator screenshot below - it's all white space. Does anyone know what may be wrong here and how I may fix it?

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, this is for an action you've developed using the Actions SDK (and not API.AI)?

Comment: Correct, using the Actions SDK.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.